# How to make this functions cleaner?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I don't want to add new lines to the JS code every time I will add a new image to the HTML. But I have no idea how to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btn').click(function() {
var bid = $(this).attr('id');
if(bid=="img1" || bid == "img2" || bid == "img3"){
    document.getElementById("img1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("img2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("img3").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("img4").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("img5").style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById(bid).style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.textures {
    background: url("images/room.png") center / cover no-repeat;
    position: static;
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
}
div>img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
[type=radio] + img {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;
    width: 80px
}
[type=radio]:checked + img {
    outline: 2px solid #000;
}
```

HTML. Here you can see if I click a radius input from the categories, it will display one of the images from materials.

```
<!--Room materials-->
<div class="textures">
    <div class="wall">
        <img id="img1" src="images/wall/blue.png" /> 
        <img id="img2" src="images/wall/brick.png" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="floor">
        <img id="img3" src="images/floor/cedro.png" /> 
        <img id="img4" src="images/floor/cipres.png" />
    </div>
</div>

<!--Categories-->
<h5>Walls</h5>
<label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn" id="img1" name="test" value="small" />
    <img src="images/thumbnail/wall/blue.png"/>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn" id="img2" name="test" value="small" />
    <img src="images/thumbnail/wall/brick.png"/> 
</label>

<h5>Floors</h5>
<label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn" id="img3" name="test" value="small" />
    <img src="images/thumbnail/floor/cedro.png"/> 
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn" id="img4" name="test" value="small" />
    <img src="images/thumbnail/floor/cipres.png"/> 
</label>
```

Example [here](http://blazeweb.net/torre402/example.php).

And [this](https://www.msisurfaces.com/virtual-kitchen-designer/) is really what I want to achieve.

Comment: `if(bid=="img1" || bid == "img2" || bid == "img3"){` doesn't make sense to me - what are you trying to do? Do you want to only show the corresponding image when its button is clicked, with the others being hidden?

Comment: sorry wrong code, edited the right one

Answer (score 1):

First of all, having duplicate IDs in a single document is **invalid HTML**. To put data in the HTML indicating a connection to another element, you could use a data attribute instead. Extract the data attribute, hide all images, then use the data attribute in a selector:

```
<input type="radio" class="btn" data-image="img4" name="test" value="small" />
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
$('.btn').on('change', function() {
  const id = $(this).data('image');
  $('.textures img').hide();
  $('#' + id).show();
});
```